Technical description of AVIF
I'm looking for a technical description of AVIF, in order to understand how it works.  Something similar to ITU T.81 from 1993 which describes clearly how JPEG works.
I'm aware of the description of AVIF file format here:
https://aomediacodec.github.io/av1-avif/v1.1.0.html
but this doesn't describe how encoding and decoding works, for instance prediction mode, block hierarchy and filters.  There is a high level description at the following website, which helps, but it doesn't explain details, or how the algorithms work:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/decoding-avif-deep-dive-with-cats-and-imgproxy
For context, I'm looking to get a "more than high level" understanding of AVIF.  For JPEG I was able to build a prototype decoder based on ITU T.81 (and sample code online), and I feel I have a good understanding of how it works - DCT, Huffman coding, YUV, quantization, 8x8 blocks...
I'd like to do the same with AVIF.  Right now I can only think of wading through libavif source code and/or the file format description, but that seems like it would take a long time.
I do appreciate AVIF is more complex than the JPEG standard from the early 1990s, but still it ought to be possible to make progress.

AVIF is a container for AV1 codec. That's why it is high level. It is just packaging of data parts. To encode/decode you must look for AV1 specs: https://aomediacodec.github.io/av1-spec/av1-spec.pdf

You're probably being tripped up by searching for AVIF and not AV1.
This may be the type of information you are looking for:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.06091#:~:text=The%20AV1%20codec%20operates%20on,some%20combinations%20of%20the%20two.

Thanks, this was helpful.  I guess the reality is that there isn't an equivalent of ITU T.81 for AV1, possibly just because it's that much more complex.  Maybe just not possible for an amateur to knock something up, unless they've got a spare week or two, or perhaps even a month.  (Unlike JPEG which isn't all that bad).
